# PHP_excel: Export to xlsx gets downloaded successfully but when we open it it shows warning Excel found unreadable content

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am using php_excel to export to xlsx. In my application im making use of template.
When i download, the xlsx file gets downloaded fine, but when we open its showing the following warning:

"**Excel found unreadable content in 'project_report(3).xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contente of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.**"

If i click yes it opens the file correctly.

And one more thing is when i attach the downloaded file to the mail. And if i open it sing Google Spread sheet it says bad format unable to open.

so if anyone know the reason please suggest me to solve this.

Comment: -1 sorry sandeep. The community working on your project whole day.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you would post your script, just the sending data to browser bit (the headers your setting)

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="project_report.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
 exit;

Comment: tried the headers i've posted? if yes: did it change anything? and you can edit your question to post the code there, what would make it more readable

Comment: To answer, we really need to know the details of what's in your workbook: something in the xlsx file is not valid, but not unrecoverable... but given the complexities of xlsx, we can't really begin to guess without more detail on the content of the file.

Comment: Check if Excel is generating a log to identify where the problem lies. This is could be in C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\ (at least under Vista)

Answer (score 0):

check your headers, here are mine:

```
   header("Pragma: public");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
   header("Content-Type: application/download");;
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

check for output (spaces before `<?php` forgotten `echo`? etc