# Windows 7: "Excel found unreadable content"

Tags: windows-7, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to generate a very simple .xls file (`PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel5')`). Whenever that file is opened on Windows 7 using Excel 2010 or 2007, I get the following error:

*Excel found unreadable content in 'XXXXXXX.xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.*

When I open the same file in Excel 2010 in Windows XP it works fine. If I open the same file in OpenOffice, it works regardless of the OS.

Windows 7 / Excel 2010: Error

Windows 7 / Excel 2007: Error

Windows XP / Excel 2010: Works

Windows XP / Excel 2007: Works

Any / OpenOffice: Works

When I tell PHPExcel to generate an .xlsx file (`PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel2007')`), it works fine with all the above combinaisons.

I found countless threads on the MS forums, and it seems to affect only Windows 7 files with Excel files generated by third party libraries (not just PHPExcel). But no one has a solution.

I also found the following MS KB article, but I'm not familiar with the underlying Excel specifications: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2411912

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are you actually generating the file on the same boxes as you're testing them (ie. on the XP box and the Windows 7 box)? Or are you copying the same file between boxes to test?

Comment: Thanks for the link: I'll take a look at the OLE sector numbers and end of chain marker... I know I need to rwerite the OLE writer anyway to support multiple streams

Comment: I'm generating the file once on a Linux server and copy/pasting it between boxes to test.

Comment: 32 bits of Windows 7/XP and also of Excel 2010/2007.

Comment: +1 for actually testing against different versions/platforms, and identifying a possible cause for the problem. You'd be amazed at how many people simply say "It don't work" whenever something isn't quite right.

Comment: I maintain a small plugin for WordPress, I understand perfectly well when you say people whine that it's not working but they never attempt to help a little. On the other hand, I almost never fill bug reports because I feel I'm not technical enough.

Comment: @kag - the effort you've made with this is more than appreciated. I've had previous reports of this "unreadable content" problem (even one here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931832/php-excel-export-to-xlsx-gets-downloded-successfully-but-when-we-open-it-it-show ) but I rarely get any response to questions asking for more information... so it's a real blessing when people have actually done some of the groundwork before posting the problem

Answer (score 2):

If it is the problem you've highlighted from the MS Support site, then it's locked somewhere in the innards of PHP_OLE, probably in the PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_File class. I've raised this as [Issue 15508](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/15508) on the PHPExcel site, and will try to run some debugging over the weekend on a Windows 7 box.

No guarantees of a quick fix: but you've given me a pointer on how to try and recreate the problem, and where to look.

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't realize you were actually a PHPExcel developer.

Comment: @kag - for my sins, I'm currently the only active developer. I'm trying to cut down on my PHPExcel work for a couple of months while I change jobs... concentrating on completing the handover for my old job at the moment, before starting a new role that will initially be very time intensive... but this qualifies as a fairly major issue, so I'll bump it up as a priority task.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was fixed when I used proper UTF-8 encoded strings instead of ISO-8859-1. Maybe PHPExcel can hint about bad encodings?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write with `UTF-8` the title, creator, LastModifiedby etc... fields. This was my solution.